# How to have more than 1 addons set installed on a single windows account?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, user-profiles

I'd like to have different addons set enabled when I'm using firefox for every day internet browsing and different addons set when I'm using firefox as web development tool.

Is there any painless way for this?

Also it would be nice to be able to use them both at the same time on the separate windows.

Answer (score 4):

You can create different Firefox profiles.
For instructions see this article: [link](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Creating_a_new_Firefox_profile_on_Windows).

Edit:
See comment about having multiple profiles active simultaneously.

Comment: Actually, multiple profiles can be active at the same time if you also use the -no-remote option with the -P option.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the [portable firefox](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable) edition for one of the two cases.